# Empty input file name when reading partitioned data using Pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have noticed that there are problems when reading partitioned data from S3 using Spark. I have data which is stored in S3 and partitioned by date columns (year, month, day, hour) but, unlike data which is written by Spark to S3, does not have column prefixes.

I could read data by using `spark.read.parquet('s3a://{bucket_name}/*/*/*/*/*.parquet)` method however when I use `input_file_name()` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` package it returns empty result. This behaviour is fixed when I remove the last segment from read method i.e. `spark.read.parquet('s3a://{bucket_name}/*/*/*/*)`. What causes such behaviour and whether this is expected but undocumented or I am reading data incorrectly?